# Create image object from image stdout output of external program in Python

Tags: python, image, subprocess, stringio

I have a program that generates pictures and either saves them to a file or prints out the raw image data in standard output. I am using Python subprocess module to call the external program, catch its stdout data and create a Python image object from the data. I keep getting "Cannot identify image file" error, though. I am new to this part of Python. Can you please help if you know how to achieve this? Here is my code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
raw = p.stdout.read()
buff = StringIO.StringIO()
buff.write(raw)
buff.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buff)
im.show()
```

Comment: What format does your subprocess output the image in?

Comment: PNG. Sorry. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. Try adding the lines...

```
assert len(raw) >= 4
assert raw.startswith('\x89PNG')
```

...directly after the line...

```
raw = p.stdout.read()
```

...just to ensure you're getting even vaguely valid data back.

**Update**

Try this...

```
from subprocess import check_output
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

raw = check_output(cmd)
buff = StringIO(raw)
im = Image.open(buff)
im.show()
```

**Update #2**

Problem is there's a bug in `qrcode.exe` whereby, when it's writing to stdout, it tries to convert UNIX line endings to DOS line endings.

Looks like the bug may have gotten fixed in a later version. Try: https://code.google.com/p/qrencode-win32/downloads/detail?name=qrcodegui_setup-3.3.1b.exe&can=1&q=qrencode-win32

Comment: Ok. I did that. No error on those assertions. I put a printed out the raw output to the console if it helps spot something. It's this (truncated): ëPNG
→
IHDR   ô   ô☺    ó₧▬╕  ☻ IDATHë▌û┴═Σ ♀à↔qαûi ë6╕╤R╥@2i`hë←m ╤@╕σ►┼√╚ƒ╒Ä┤↨|²Qä&▀H
æ♠      ½|N▲á\ε\‼^%,Ü┼¥C╠CΣÜh▬▓9frτDê*fïcÄ%░┌ñ♀yP&ƒ↨G≤Wn=♀·═╔<╧?M╗X[◄☼♫┬ßδ.{╪NfH
σú╧┼ùÅ

Comment: How about if you dump the entire raw var to a file, with something like `open('test.png', 'wb').write(raw)`, and then open it with an image viewer?

Comment: That actually works. I tried that already, so I am sure that the file that is produced by the external file is correct. I am just trying to avoid the step of saving the file to a hard drive first and then loading it to save it. I need to do this 30 times a seconds, so it would be nice to do this all in memory. ;)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your installation of PIL doesn't include a PNG decoder for some reason, although I'm not sure how to check - does it also fail if you do `im = Image.open('test.png')` on the image you just saved?

Comment: When I do that, it works fine - no error. Strange. I guess I will resort to saving the image to a file first and then load it again. It can be done 30 times a second. It's just ugly engineering. Thanks for helping, though!

Comment: That's pretty strange. Lemme check something else.

Comment: I tried your updated code and gives the same output error as before. Did you try this yourself with something that generates PNGs? I mean, is this working for you? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I just tested it with `cmd = ['cat', 'test.png']` and it's fine. What exactly is the command you're running, and does it only output a single image, or multiple images?

Comment: I am using the qrcode.exe executable that you can find in this zip file to generate QR codes: https://code.google.com/p/qrencode-win32/downloads/detail?name=qrcode-win32-3.1.1.zip&can=1&q= There is also a bat file containing a sample of how to call the command. You can pass it to the check_output() function's cmd parameter like this: cmd = ['qrcode.exe', '-o', '-', 'text to encode']. This generates a PNG and sends it to standard output. At least that's the way I understand it from the help.

Comment: Aaah, it's working now. That was it! Thanks a million times! I wish I could give you more than one point. I will give you some for the intermediate answers for your tenacity! :)